# How to replace script in variable and use variable in script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, sed

I need to replace`sed` line in this script in variables and after use just variables.

```
cat postfix > "file.html" 
cal -h | sed '1{s|^|<table>\n<tr><th colspan="7">|;s|$|</th></tr>|};2,${s|\(..\) |<td>\1</td>|g;s|^|<tr>|;s|$|</tr>|};$s|$|\n</table>|' >> file.html
cat prefix >> "file.html"'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like

```
expression='1{s|^|<table>\n<tr><th colspan="7">|;s|$|</th></tr>|};2,${s|\(..\) |<td>\1</td>|g;s|^|<tr>|;s|$|</tr>|};$s|$|\n</table>|'

cat postfix > "file.html"
cal -h | sed "${expression}" >> file.html
cat prefix >> "file.html"
```

(and noting that normally one would expect the prefix to go at the head, and the postfix at the end... ; but that's what one would expect, based on their names)

Comment: how do replace script in variables in other file and use that variables in this file?

Comment: You could place the content of the expression in one or more files and read those in and concatenate; expression="$(cat "expressions.txt")" or more files: expression="$(cat "expression_header.txt" "expression_middle.txt" "expression_footer.txt")"

Answer (score 0):

Although `sed` in this occasion may do the trick, I think it is not a good idea if this code needs to be maintained.

A small remark about the pre- and post-files: in general, prefix is something you put before, and postfix is something you put after. Doing it the other way around adds to the confusion.

What you want, is to have the first line as header and the rest split-out in table-cells.

```
cal -h > tempfile
cat postfix > "file.html"
echo '<table>' >> "file.html"
echo '<tr><th colspan="7">' >> "file.html"
head -1 tempfile >> "file.html"
echo '</th></tr>' >> "file.html"
tail +1 | sed 's/^/<tr>;s/\(/<td>/g;s/\)/<\/td>/g;s/$/<\/tr>/' >> "file.html"
echo '</table>' >> "file.html"
rm tempfile
```

which already makes it a bit more readable.

or even further:

```
first=yes
cat postfix > "file.html" #sic
echo '<table>' >> "file.html"
cal -h | while read line ; do
    if [ $first = yes ] ; then
        first=no
        echo "<tr><th colspan=\"7\">$line</th></tr>" >> "file.html"
    else
        tdopen=${line//\(/<td>}
        tdclose=${tdopen//\)/<\/td>}
        echo "<tr>$tdclose</tr>" >> "file.html"
    fi
done
echo '</table>' >> "file.html"
cat prefix >> "file.html" #sic
```

which, I think, is more readable than the `sed`-clutter. But that is just my personal preference.